# What's a good number for IOPS (RDS)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I recently verified the IOPS in my RDS instances IOPS and I believe that it is too high. What is considered a good number/average for IOPS?

Are there any tools to check integrity and problems in a Mysql instance to help lower the IOPS, better than what is seen below?

[image]

Comment: A good IOPS is a zero IOPS.

Comment: Too high?  This number is very small.  3 IOPS/GB of storage is high on a basic configuration, if the provisioned storage is >= 100 GiB.  For smaller storage allocations, 300 IOPS is a standard value for reference.

Answer (score 1):

A good number is rarely peaking to the available IOPS of the hardware or Cloud provider.

Your graph show rarely getting over 25.  That is a very low number.

AWS carves up machines and sells you different amounts of CPU and IO.  I can't say what your max is.

If you are hitting limits of CPU or IO with MySQL, then the first thing to do is to find the slowest query.  It may need a better index, probably a 'composite' index.  Or it may need to be reformulated in some simple way.  Only after that, I would look at tuning.  Then at hardware or AWS plan.